# Swift 2.2 - Cannot subscript a value type of '[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: arrays, dictionary, subscript, swift2

I have a function defined below:

```
private func append(inout ret: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]?, element: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

    if ret == nil {
        ret = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]()
        ret?.append(element)
        return
    }

    let retGateways = ret!["gateways"] as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] // ERROR: Cannot subscript...

    // more commands...
}
```

Where `ret` can be:

```
[[“name”: “NameA”, “gateways”: [[“id”: “ID1”, “name”: “Name1”], [“id”: “ID2”, “name”: “Name2”]]]]
```

and `element` can be

```
[“name”: “NameB”, “gateways”: [[“id”: “ID3”, “name”: “Name3”], [“id”: “ID4”, “name”: “Name4”]]]
```

The error that I got is `Cannot subscript a value type of '[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]' with an index of type 'String'`.

I have referenced to some threads here but it still does not wipe out this error.

Please show me how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see.

In my function, `ret` is an `Array`, not a `Dictionary`.